# Populating dropdown via AJAX Fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am looking to populate a dropdown via AJAX in my MVC project.  In doing so, the "Network" debugging tools show a 404 when searching my url and always falls into the error function of my AJAX call.

My Javascript, which is housed at the bottom of my view, is as follows:

```
function PopulateTournamentDropdown() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Leaderboard/PopulateTournamentDropDownList',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                var ddlTournament = $("#ddlTournament");
                ddlTournament.empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, tournament) {
                    ddlTournament.append('<option value="' + tournament.Id + '">' + tournament.Name + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Failed to retrieve tournament.');
            }
        });
    }

    $(function () {

        $('#ddlTournament').change(PopulateTournamentDropdown);
        PopulateTournamentDropdown();
    });
```

My Controller is as follows:

```
public class LeaderboardController : Controller
    {
        public static string PopulateTournamentDropDownList()
        {
            var list = GetTournamentDetails();
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, JsonSetting);
        }
}
```

As of now, the method in the controller is never being hit.

Please Help.

Comment: I am not sure but aren't you missing `List` from `'/Leaderboard/PopulateTournamentDropdown'` ? Should be `'/Leaderboard/PopulateTournamentDropdownList'`

Comment: I appologize.  I copied wrong.  I do have List included in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the Action being a static method. Can you try this:

```
public class LeaderboardController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PopulateTournamentDropDownList()
    {
        var list = GetTournamentDetails();
        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, JsonSetting), "application/json");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked.  I was under the impression that all methods in MVC that returned ActionMethods, had to return Views.  The Content() is a new concept for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The controller action method should have the following signature:

```
public ActionResult PopulateTournamentDropDownList()
{
  ...
}
```

Note, that it is instance (not static) method.

Comment: So in order to make any AJAX call in MVC, I have to return an ActionResult which will have to return a string?  Is there any way to return a JsonResult or JSON string via AJAX in MVC?